# Does it sound natural in English?

Tags: phrase-usage

Does the following sound natural in English?

> Our organization is well disciplined.
> Our decision-making is prudent.
> The overall atmosphere of our company is creative, innovative and forward-looking.
> I have done a good job after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of it sounds like classic marketing-speak. It might come out of a company brochure. The last sentence, while perfectly natural on its own, does not seem to me to fit the rest of the passage. It changes from describing "**our** company" is like, to evaluating what "**I**" has done, judging it. Perhaps the speaker is trying to convince himself or herself.